# Could equestrian prefects sit on sella curulis?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire, furniture

Were prefects of less than important provinces of the early principatus (like Pilate) allowed to sit on the ivory [curule seat](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Curule_seat.html), or *sella curulis*, that curule magistrates and promagistrates used while performing their official duties? If not, then what was their seat like?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The *[sella curulis](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Curule_seat.html)* was:

> "...  the seat upon which magistrates holding [imperium](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Imperium.html) were entitled to sit. This includes dictators, magistri equitum, consuls, praetors, censors, curule aediles, and the promagistrates, temporary or de facto holders of such offices.

Now, it is important to note that:

> "No ancient authority defines imperium"

- [Sherwin-White, [Roman Society and Roman Law in the New Testament](https://azbyka.ru/otechnik/assets/uploads/books/18478/Adrian%20Nicholas%20Sherwin-White%20Roman%20Society%20and%20Roman%20Law%20in%20the%20New%20Testament.pdf), p3]

Nevertheless, the historian A.H.N. Jones is quoted in Brent Kinman's [Jesus' Entry Into Jerusalem](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pRdiwjAeYLkC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=Praefectus%20imperium%20Pilate&source=bl&ots=0tbCSJtsFo&sig=I6IJ2GABDQAOiIm8nypEdA1RufU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi517i58uHYAhVBK8AKHcMlBGMQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=Praefectus%20imperium%20Pilate&f=false) as follows:

> It has often been doubted whether Praefecti, like Legati, held an imperium delegated to them by their proconsul, but there is no good reason for denying it. They were assigned tasks similar in kind, and differing only in scale, from those assigned to Legati, and the execution of these tasks required imperium ..."

So it would seem that as Prefect of the Roman province of Judaea (*Praefectus Iudaeae*) Pilate did hold imperium, and so was entitled to sit on the *sella curulis*. It should be remembered that the title "Prefect" was still a military one under Tiberius.

---

The situation seems to have changed when the military title "Prefect" was changed to the civilian title "Procurator" under Claudius (see [Pontius Pilate in History and Interpretation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gvh9km_b7gsC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Helen K. Bond, p12).

From this point, the Procurators were no longer magistrates, and (according to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_governor#Equestrian_procurator)):

> *"so did not possess imperium, and merely exercised the Emperor’s, or governor's, authority with his approval."*

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure that the Praefectus Iudaeae actually held imperium? Not everyone in the military is imperium holder, and I have read somewhere that prefects could not even command a legion of roman citiziens, and used auxiliaries only.

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I was doing some further reading, and it seems that when the posts were changed to "Procurator" under Claudius they were no longer magistrates, and (according to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_governor#Equestrian_procurator)) "_so did not possess imperium, and merely exercised the Emperor’s, or governor's, authority with his approval._"